# Thunderbirds F.A.B

Tags: thunderbirds

In Gerry Anderson's 'Thunderbirds'(1965-66), the Tracy brothers (Scott, John, Virgil, Gordon and Alan) would respond on the radio

> "F.A.B."

meaning 'affirmative' or 'understood'.

---

There are many theories as to the meaning to this acronym.  While watching 'The Right Stuff', I noted that Virgil Grissom would respond to the other astronauts with the phrase

> ***F..... A, Bubba!***

meaning 'affirmative' or 'understood'.

Given that this was a phrase used by the [real Mercury Astronauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_Seven), five of whom were the namesakes for the Tracy boys, **could this Gerry Anderson's source for the acronym?**

Comment: Did you mean to say “Now, The movie ‘The Right Stuff’(1983) would not be considered the source,” or are you providing an answer to your question?

Comment: Perhaps I should have said 'could not be considered the source' as the film was made in 1983, and the book was written in 1979, both after the t.v. show in question.

Comment: @Scott - Better to make it clear that the astronauts used this language in the 1950 and 1960s but that you learned of it from a film...

Comment: @Valorum-Look man, I was really just asking a question.  If you want to ask my question your own way, then please feel free on your own post.  I think you have some good clarifications of what I wanted to know, but I did delete the expletive.  I don't need a lesson on how to curse in a public forum.  You really didn't need to veil it so lightly.

Comment: You might also want to have a read of http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: I read somewhere (can't remember but will try and find a source), that it stood for 'Full audio broadcast'

Comment: Why do I remember as a kid thinking it stood for Fire All Boosters? (I remember this because I remember thinking it didn't make that much sense), the only place I could've got this is from the TV show, Comics or Toys (ie not the internet)

Answer (score 9):

If those real-life astronauts provided the show with any inspiration beyond their names, I can't find documentation to support it--in fact, quite the opposite.

[Gerry Anderson says](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/entertainment/1002177.stm) F.A.B isn't meant to be an abbreviation for any particular phrase; the real-life inspiration was "fabulous" ("fab" was a common slang in the 60s) and that's it.

> FAB stands for absolutely nothing! In the Sixties when the series was made the abbreviation "fab" as in "fabulous" was all the rage and I just changed it a bit.

There's apparently a tie-in comic where F.A.B means "For Always Brothers," but I can't track down the source yet. Even [that citation](http://www.lbc.co.uk/what-does-fab-stand-for-in-thunderbirds-21317) points out it's just one issue of a comic (whose writers probably had little to no contact with the TV show).

Comment: According to here: http://gerryanderson.co.uk/question/what-does-fab-stand-for/ - it stands for nothing. However ."..If it was an acronym, then the best suggestion we’ve heard for a potential meaning is “Fully Acknowledged Broadcast”. "

Comment: @Alistair86 I'm not clear on who the "we" is in that source.

Comment: According to his twitter bio - Jamie is 'Producer/director/writer, proud son of legendary #Thunderbirds creator GerryAndersonTV'

Comment: [Yes he can](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33498293#33498293).

Answer (score 2):

**Officially** *'Nothing'*

**Potentially** *'Fully Acknowledged Broadcast'*.

Taken from [What does FAB stand for?](http://gerryanderson.co.uk/question/what-does-fab-stand-for/):

> "This has got to be one of the most asked questions: What does FAB stand for in Thunderbirds? **Well here’s the answer in one simple word: Nothing!** In the 60’s the buzz-word was “fabulous”. This was shortened to FAB and used simply as a call sign like ‘Roger’ or ‘Ten-Four’ to acknowledge received instructions. ***If it was an acronym, then the best suggestion we’ve heard for a potential meaning is “Fully Acknowledged Broadcast”***. So now, next time someone asks you what FAB stands for, you can give them the authoritative answer: nothing!"

The above was written by [Jamie Anderson](https://twitter.com/ImJamieAnderson), son of creator Gerry Anderson.

Comment: Another popular theory back in the proverbial day was "Full Ahead Brothers".

I always loved on in Captain Scarlet they had the acronym "SIG", which they explained clearly ("Spectrum is Green" as well as the negative, SIR for "Spectrum is Red") in the first episode, getting it out of the way straight off.